# What was the career of Patrick Golden on the 1870 census?

Tags: census-records, 18th-century, palaeography, massachusetts

I am unable to read what follows "Painter" in [the 1870 federal census record for Patrick Golden of Boston](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MD3Y-MLR):

[image: screenshot of census record]

What is in parentheses after his name? It appears to start with "H".

Here is the full page:
[image: Full page of census record]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the occupation written is:

> Painter (House)

Although not capitalized, there are two entries for

> Keeps house

in the following few rows that you can use to compare the "ouse" ending to the word.